# How to filter array of Observable element | RxSwift

Tags: swift3, rx-swift

I have a struct Person and person array as following

```
struct Person {
  let name : String
  let age : Int
}

let personArray = [
    Person(name : "Max", age : 32),
    Person(name : "Jones", age : 42),
    Person(name : "Other", age : 62)
]
```

I create an observable sequence as following

```
let seq = Observable.just(personArray)
```

now How can I filter this array by relevant person name ?

e.g. I want an observable sequence that contains person `name` that starts with 'M'

how to do this ??

Comment: You can make use of BehaviorRelay which can work as an observable and you can easily change its value as well. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
let seq = Observable.just(personArray)


seq.just(personArray)
   .map{
       $0.filter{ $0.name.hasPrefix("M")}
   }
   .subscribe(onNext: { item in
       print(item)
   })
```

You also could do this:

```
let seq = Observable.just(personArray.filter{ $0.name.hasPrefix("M") })
```

Comment: I need it to work from result that produce by Observable.just(). because i want to bind that to a table later

Comment: @XFreire thanks, but why isn't this possible? `seq.just(personArray).filter{ $0.name.hasPrefix("M") }`

Comment: @markturnip because it's an array of `Person`, not multiple `Person` objects. You need to iterate inside the array to check the prefix. Otherwise, the array doesn't have a property name.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple playground example that I used to prototype the same problem:

```
import RxSwift

let dataSource = Observable.just([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
let filterSource = PublishSubject<Int>()

Observable
    .combineLatest(dataSource, filterSource) { data, filter in data.filter { $0 != filter } }
    .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })

filterSource.onNext(3)
filterSource.onNext(2)

print("Done")
```

This prints:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 5]
Done
```

Answer (score 1):

Chris' answer was correct for me. I'd like to share also my implementation, I have a tableview of objects that needs to be filtered from searchbar.

You will notice I have

- cards
- filteredCards
- cardToSearch

.

```
override init(){
    super.init()
    cards = loadCardsRx().asObservable()

    filteredCards = Observable.combineLatest(cards, cardToSearch){ data, filter in
        data.filter{ $0.naziv?.lowercased().hasPrefix(filter.lowercased()) ?? true}}
    }

    var cards:Observable<[Card]>!
    var filteredCards:Observable<[Card]>!
    var cardToSearch:BehaviorRelay<String> = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
```

I even tried removing the *filteredCards* observable and reassigning cards to be the filtered one, it works but I'm not certain if it is correct, maybe someone more experienced can help with this.

```
override init(){
    super.init()
    cards = loadCardsRx().asObservable()

    cards = Observable.combineLatest(cards, cardToSearch){ data, filter in
        data.filter{ $0.naziv?.lowercased().hasPrefix(filter.lowercased()) ?? true}}
}

var cards:Observable<[Card]>!
var cardToSearch:BehaviorRelay<String> = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
```